# How to configure log levels in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to have gradle read a logging.properties file in order to set logging levels by  class?  What I want to do is to see *my* debug statements, but not the debug statements for every class being used.  I.e., I'd like to use `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=mylogging.properties`.

[This topic](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/unable_to_configure_java_util_logging_with_gradle_test_task) on the gradle forum refers to [the class](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/379def16e573f7a73a9b5ace9e5c2c69dbb2d0f2/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/junit/JULRedirector.java) that hijacks the ConsoleHandler but I wasn't sure if the same thing applies for non-testing tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something that's currently supported. There might be a hack to achieve it, but I'm not aware of one. The easy (if somewhat limited) solution is to filter the output after-the-fact, e.g. with a `grep` or by using a log viewer.

Comment: Is there a way to turn on logging project wide with a setting file? E.g. setting the --info flag in gradle.properties?

Comment: You could set `gradle.startParameter.logLevel` from a build script.

Comment: I've tried doing `gradle.startParameter.setLogLevel LogLevel.INFO` and `logging.setLevel LogLevel.INFO` in the root build.gradle to no effect. The subprojects all report `println logging.level` as `INFO` but it doesn't change any of the script output at all. Using the `--info` flag works as expected.

Comment: Setting the log level in the build script might be too late. I'm not aware of another way to achieve this. What's the use case?

Comment: Trying to get more log output from a build failure on Google's "Release Pipelines". As yet, they don't offer any option for command line flags.

Answer (score 19):

Add this line to `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.logging.level=info
```

will have the same effect as `gradle --info`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me. I am using Gradle 3.1.

```
import static org.gradle.api.logging.LogLevel.*

project.logger.quiet "1. Level: quiet"
project.logger.error "1. Level: error"
project.logging.setLevelInternal(ERROR)
project.logger.quiet "2. Level: quiet"
project.logger.error "2. Level: error"
```

Barry

Comment: Where do you put these? In the `build.gradle` file?