# How to disable Gradle DEBUG logs?

Tags: gradle

Gradle v4.10.3 - old I know but we're not able to upgrade yet.

How do I set Gradle daemon logs so `DEBUG` logs, like the one below, are not shown in the `~/.gradle/daemon/<version>/daemon*.log` files?

```
14:43:04.814 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain] Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=1g, -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1048m, -Xmx2048M, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
```

I've tried suggestions in, for example, [How to configure log levels in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19685048/how-to-configure-log-levels-in-gradle) to no avail.